# Problem regarding radius of convergence of $\sum n!x^{n^2}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^{n^2}$$

Can anyone tell me what will be the radius of convergence for this power series. According to me it is $0$.

If you can please show me how to go about it if I am wrong.

Comment: How did you arrive at $0$?

Comment: By using the method of |U_(n+1)/U_(n)|.

Comment: It ends up in the form 1/ n^(1/(2n+1)) as n tends to infinity . I am not clear what this value will tend to. But I have assumed it tends to 0 as n tends to infinity

Comment: This ?$$\frac{1}{ n^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}}$$

Comment: Actually it should be (n+1) instead of n in the denominator rest is OK

Comment: It is $0$. See : Hadamard Radius Formula.

Comment: @user254665 in the formula you have mentioned the power of the exponent is of first degree and here our question has the exponent in second degree ,so I don't think hadamard formula is applicable here.

Comment: The radius is $1$.(I miscalculated). And Hadamard's formula IS applicable. When  $a_m=0$ when $m>1$ is not a square, and  $a_m=(sqrt m)!$ when $m$ is a square. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup{j>n}|a_j|^{1/j}=$ $\lim_{m\to \infty}n!^{1/n^2}=1$ by Stirling's Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's treat this power series as a 'series'.

We will be using root test here.

Let $x$ be fixed. According to the root test, For the convergence of given series we need to assure that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |n! x^{n^2}|^{\frac 1n} \lt 1.$ That is, for sufficiently large values of $n$, $\; |n! x^{n^2}|^{\frac 1n} \lt 1 \Rightarrow |n!|^{\frac 1n}|x^n| \lt 1 \Rightarrow |x^n| \lt |n!|^{-\frac 1n} \Rightarrow |x| \lt |n!|^{-\frac 1{n^2}}$.

Hence $|x| \lt \lim_{n \to \infty} |n!|^{-\frac 1{n^2}}=1$.

Hence the series converges for $|x| \lt 1$. i.e. Radius of convergence is $1$.

**EDIT 1:** The root test says that ''If $\lim |a_n|^{\frac 1n} \lt 1$, then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.'' Our $a_n$ here is $n!x^{n^2}$.

**EDIT 2:** For evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} |n!|^{-\frac 1{n^2}}$,

Take $y_n={n!}^{- \frac 1{n^2}} \Rightarrow \ln y_n = -\frac {\ln n!}{n^2}= \frac {\ln \frac 1{n!}}{n^2} \; .\;. \;. \;. \;. \;. \;. \; (1)$

Now $\frac {n \ln \frac 1n}{n^2} \lt \ln y_n \lt \frac {n \ln1}{n^2}$.

Since left side inequality and right side inequalities $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,hence by sandwitch thoeorem, $\lim \; \ln y_n =\ln y=0 \Rightarrow y=1$. $\; (\text{Let} \; y_n \to y).$

Comment: Can you show the procedure?

Comment: The actual limit is different.

Comment: It should be $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^\frac{1}{2n+1}$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I am using root test for convergence of a series $\sum a_n$. The test says that ''if $\lim |a_n|^{\frac 1n} \lt 1$, then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.'' My $a_n$ here is $n! x^{n^2}$

Comment: Ok thats fine. I know about the root test. The limit I just gave was the radius of convergence.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat That's why I mentioned very first that let's look at this power series as a series. :) Then root test does the job as you can see from wolfram alpha links that I have showed you.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat So radius of convergence turns out to be $1$.

Comment: How does the ROC come to be 1? Show me that part. You just showed me the root test one.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Okay root test does shows us $|x| \lt 1$. By definition of radius of convergence, $R$ is radius of convergence of a power series if the series is absolutely convergent on $|x| \lt R$.

Comment: Note that $a_n$ is independent of $x$. So the edit that you have written is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53849/discussion-between-vikrant-desai-and-schrodingerscat).

Comment: @SchrodingersCat For every $-1 \lt x \lt 1$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$. Again note that I've taken $a_n=n! x^{n^2}$.

Comment: @Vikrant Desai a_n is independent of variable x either you say u_n or else its wrong.

Comment: @shadowkh Okay. Then take $u_n= n! x^{n^2}$ and replace it wherever $a_n$ is.

Comment: In fact I like the way you have explained the answer. The right answer is indeed 1.

Comment: @shadowkh I have made EDIT 2 look more easy by sandwich theorem. Thanks. :) I also learned many things that I didn't know before while solving this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence is given by $R^{-1}=\mathbb{lim\ sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}} |a_{n}|^{1/n}=\mathbb{lim\ sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}} n!^{1/n^2}=1$.

Edit: I don't know all the forms of the ratio test, but the other answers compute a limit that, in this case, does not exist because we have "holes" in the power serie (the only coefficients that appears are of the form $x^{n^2}$)

Comment: My edit was "ratio" for "radio".  BTW the lim sup IS a limit. It's $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$ where $b_n=\sup \{|a_m|^{1/m}:m>n\}$..............+1

Answer (score 0):

Radius of convergence, R is given by:
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\right|^\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\right|^\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes sure I was expecting this ans

Comment: You're right. They will not be closed intervals but open intervals. Thanks.

Comment: This is a power series in $x$, so the radius of convergence should not depend on $x$.

Comment: Oh yes. Dont know what I was thinking. Correcting it right now.

Comment: @JohnGowers I have corrected it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you calculated radius of convergence for $\sum n! x^n$. Have a look at my answer. :)

Comment: @SchrodingersCat With the edit, you are no longer committing the error of computing the radius of convergence for $\sum n! x^n$, but the exponent $1/(2n+1)$ is very poorly explained.  It is non-sensical to compute the limit of $a_n/a_{n+1}$ when $a_n = 0$ infinitely often (I am making an assumption about how you define $a_n$, but this is another thing you have left unexplained).

Comment: I stand corrected the answer is 1 and I have found where I went wrong

Comment: This question was from JAM 2017 Mathematics paper.Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it was and it is given as 1 by many institution